# Find continuous functions between two topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ be a standard topological space on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $B_\delta=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2: |x_1-x_2|<\delta\}$.

Let $\tau^*=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}^2, B_\delta\}$, for all $\delta>0$.
It is easy to show that $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau^*)$ is a topological space.

My question is how to find all continuous functions $f:(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau^*) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All such continuous functions must be constant. To see this, suppose that $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is $\tau^*/\tau$-continuous. Fix an arbitrary $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2$ and define $c\equiv f(x_1,x_2)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since the interval $(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$ is open in $\tau$, its preimage $f^{-1}((c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon))$ must be open in $\tau^*$. Now, $f^{-1}((c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon))$ contains $(x_1,x_2)$ (which means it is not empty), so this preimage must be equal either to $\mathbb R^2$ or to $B_{\delta}$ for some $\delta>0$. In either case, $f^{-1}((c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon))$ contains $(0,0)$, which means that $$|f(0,0)-c|<\varepsilon.$$ This is true for any $\varepsilon>0$, so that $f(0,0)=c=f(x_1,x_2)$. But, once again, $(x_1,x_2)$ had been arbitrarily chosen.